# Date: Year Scrolldown/up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My date picker can only scroll down/up to 20 years only for e.g. 2005 - 2025
I want it to be 1935-2025. Is it possible to change or edit it?

Well here's the code thank you!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+10w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+10w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you select an early year, the year list will be different the next time you click on it, an will let you select even earlier years. Is that sufficient? Or, do you want it to show earlier years when you first click the year combobox? Keep in mind, if you make it too big, it might sprawl vertically on PCs, and the user may need to scroll to find the value they want.

Comment: Well its not efficient for me since its for birthday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [yearRange](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) option:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+10w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:1997',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+10w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:1997' ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I do it for 1935-1997 rather than 1935-2015? :)

Comment: Simple, just change this part `yearRange: '1935:'+(new Date).getFullYear(),` to this
`yearRange: '1935':'1997,'`

Comment: For both the `#to` and `#from` `datepicker`. Let me know if you have trouble :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92530/discussion-between-vista-and-rofls).

Comment: I think you got it fixed, but `'1935':'1997,'` was a typo, should have been `'1935':'1997',`. Sorry